# /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby3.0’: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I try to run this command `sudo bundle exec rake ridge:apply ALLOW_DROP_TABLE=1 ALLOW_REMOVE_COLUMN=1`

but get this following error `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby3.0’: No such file or directory`

after that I use `which ruby` to see the location which is in `/home/hai/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Then I created a soft link `sudo ln -sv /home/hai/.rbenv/shims/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`

but still get the same error.

`ruby -v` gives me `ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Some file has an incorrect "hashbang" setting. It should be `/usr/bin/env ruby` not `/usr/bin/env ruby3.0`.

Comment: I checked it with `head -n 1 bin/rails` on my project and get `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Comment: Something, somewhere, in your system references this oddball `ruby3.0` binary that is not standard on most distributions. You'll need to track that down.

Comment: What does that rake task look like? It seems custom given the fact that "rake ridge:apply" on google only returns this post.